# Question about sharing documents via SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

I have about 100 research articles that I’d like to share with other SharePoint users.

What would be the best way to go about doing that via SharePoint? I add an additional 10 or so each month so I’d like a way for someone to know what the article is about before they d/l the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the sharepoint blog feature.  This way you can use your blog as the news feed and update when you want.

You can use windows live writer to post directly to the blog as well: http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer?os=other

As for the documents you should use a regular document library for those and then use links within the blog to link to them.